# How to display custom admin pointers (tips/notifications) in Dashboard until dismissed?

Tags: customization, dashboard

When I updated Wordpress to 4.9.6 I saw a little info-box showing a tip/notification about the new Integrity settings in the dashboard.
Is it possible to create custom info-boxes like this and point them at menu items in the dashboard for a first-time user?

How would you achieve this?

EDIT: Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Persist Admin Notices](https://github.com/collizo4sky/persist-admin-notices-dismissal) code available on github for admin notices.

[EDIT]
What you're looking for are [Admin Pointers](https://www.wpexplorer.com/making-themes-plugins-more-usable/#heading-admin-pointers).  There are used to help users navigate/use some new functionality.

Comment: That is standard notices. I found that, but what I am looking for is more like this one: https://blogaid.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/wordpress-4-9-6-privacy-personal-data-notice.png

Comment: edited the answer with a link to a code example...